# Error in mail configuration in php

Tags: email, phpmailer

I designed my website and hosted on my amazon ec2 instance and I bought my domain in godaddy (www.mydomain.com).Now I want a mail configuration in my contact form page in website.. Below its my code , I don't know where am I mistake the code?

```
  <?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
            try {
                $name = $_POST['name'];

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$name')</script>";

                $email = $_POST['email'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$email')</script>";

                 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$subject')</script>";

                 $message = $_POST['message'];
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message')</script>";

                 $response ="";
                 $body ="<div style='font-size:18px'>
                     <b>Name</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : $name  <br />
                     <b>Email address</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: $email  <br />
                     <b>Message</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : $message <br />
                </div>"


                $to = "XXXXX@gmail.com";

                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/samplemail/lib/class.phpmailer.php');
                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/samplemail/lib/class.smtp.php');

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                //$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"; // your SMTP Server
                // echo $res;

                $mail->IsSMTP();

                $mail->Host      = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
                $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
                $mail->SMTPAuth  = true; // Auth Type
                $mail->Port      = 25;

                $mail->IsSendmail(); 
                //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

                $mail->Username = "support@mydomain.com";
                $mail->Password = "******";
                $mail->Sender   = "supportexample@mydomain.com";
                $mail->From     = "supportexample@mydomain.com";

                $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

                $mail->FromName = "Example";
                $mail->AddAddress($to);
                //$mail->AddAddress("desired recipient no.2 optional");
                $mail->IsHTML(true);

                $mail->Subject  = $subject;
                $mail->Body     = $body;
                $mail->WordWrap = 50;

               If($mail->Send()){

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Mail Send Successfully')</script>";
}
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed')</script>";
                echo $e->errorMessage();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I got this error. How do solve this issue?

> Could not execute: /var/qmail/bin/sendmail

Answer (score 0):

You can't call random functions and expect it to all work magically.

You're setting up for SMTP with `isSMTP()`, but then ignoring all that by calling `isSendmail()`, when it looks like your server simply isn't set up for it. Why do that? Re-enable isSMTP and configure your script for your mail server correctly.

You're also requesting auth while disabling encryption; that's likely to fail on any modern server.

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, and you've based your code on an obsolete example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on [the examples provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).

Comment: That's irrelevant - it's the one you're trying to use that counts.